# Combining multiple SQL UPDATE queries with a single WHERE statement

Tags: sql-server

I am running a program which requires several SQL Queries, all very similar in structure. I would like to combine them into a single Query using IFF statements but somehow that doesn't work. The examples below should illustrate what I am trying to do. Many thanks for any help.

QUERY 1 ---

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table2.Column1 = Table1.Column5
WHERE Table1.Column1 = 'A' 
AND Table1.Column2 = 'B';
```

QUERY 2 ---

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table2.Column1 = Table1.Column6
WHERE Table1.Column1 = 'A' AND
Table1.Column2 = 'C';
```

ATTEMPTED QUERY ---

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table2.Column1 = Iif(Table1.Column2 = 'B', Table1.Column5, 'X'), 
    Tabl2.Column2 = Iif(Table1.column2 = 'C', Table1.Column6, 'X')
WHERE Table1.Column1 = 'A';
```

Comment: 'does not work' is not a useful technical description of what's going wrong. do you get any error or unexpected result?

Comment: You can't update 2 tables in the same update statement in SQL Server.

Comment: @EduardUta It's true, you can't, but he's actually trying to update one table. Just check the attempted query.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query that you're actually looking for, based on your attempted query, is:

```
UPDATE T2
SET T2.Column1 = CASE WHEN T1.Column2 = 'B' THEN T1.Column5 ELSE 'X' END,
    T2.Column2 = CASE WHEN T1.Column2 = 'C' THEN T1.Column6 ELSE 'X' END
FROM Table2 T2, Table1 T1
WHERE T1.Column1 = 'A'
```

Comment: You can't update 2 tables in the same update statement in SQL Server.

Comment: @EduardUta It's true you can't update two tables, but he's actually  trying to update one table, with values from the other table. My query is correct, so pleae change your downvote to an upvote.

Comment: I think it would also make sense to use JOIN between the two tables and not the old syntax (with comma). Of course, the joining columns need to be added by the OP.

Comment: @EduardUta Yes, a JOIN would be prefered, but I don't know between what columns.